# Script for duplicating ExpressionEngine installation

Tags: ssh, phpmyadmin, expressionengine

For our development purposes, we have a base template installation of ExpressionEngine which is duplicated whenever we start a new project. This process involves copying the directory contents and changing ownership via SSH, then synchronizing the databases via phpMyAdmin.

I was wondering if it might be possible to compile a batch script (or equivalent) to perform all these operations via a single terminal command, and if so, I would appreciate some basic foundation on which to build the script.

Comment: Note that the SYnchronization feature has been removed from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/sh

cp -R /foo /bar
chmod 644 /bar/*
mysql < default.sql
```

Note that I'm just importing a default file to MySQL, not synchronizing two different sets of data, but it doesn't sound like that's what you meant anyway.